# How to display each file found progressbar before deleting with bash script

Tags: bash, progress-bar, cross-platform

I'm trying to create a script that looks into a folder, filters out files to delete and display each filename to be deleted, then delete it. It's purpose is to be displayed in the terminal mode, not like platform GUI.
TOOLD is inparameter for how many days back in time I shall leave as is

```
FOUNDFILES=$(find log*.BAK -mtime +${TOOLD} | wc -l)
echo "Found $FOUNDFILES files to remove"
echo "Looking $TOOLD days back in time"

if [ $FOUNDFILES -gt 0 ]
then
    MESS1="$FOUNDFILES to remove"
    COUNTER=0
    ProgressBar ${COUNTER} ${FOUNDFILES}
fi
```

Function ProgressBar purpose is to see how far gone in the job the script is.

```
# Create ProgressBar function
# Input is currentState($1) and totalState($2) call like this:
# ProgressBar  param1 param2 
function ProgressBar {
# Process data
  let _progress=(${1}*100/${2}*100)/100
  let _done=(${_progress}*4)/10
  let _left=40-$_done 
# Build progressbar string lengths
 _fill=$(printf "%${_done}s")
 _empty=$(printf "%${_left}s")

# Build progressbar strings and print the ProgressBar line
# Output example:
# Progress : [##########################.......] 73%
printf "\rProgress : [${_fill// /#}${_empty// /-}] ${_progress}%%"
```

}

While above produce a numeric information, below give me filenames but always just 10 files???
Hence if I execute rm as commented out, I delete files in bunches.

```
LOGFILES_TO_DELETE=$(ls -lrt logman_files/log*.BAK |  head )
echo "$LOGFILES_TO_DELETE"
echo "done listing, lets execute"
# rm -f {$LOGFILES_TO_DELETE} \; >/dev/null 2>&1
```

So my question is how to combine this into below output ( each filename i delete, number of total, and the progress below it)? What am I missing/doing wrong?

```
 # Output as I want it:
 Deleting : logfile1093.BAK  (<deleting_no> of <total_2_delete )
 Progress : [###################.........] 73%
```

Edit----
Found this code to work (replace in above) but nothing is deleted by rm below. Any ideas?

```
FOUNDFILES=$(find boxlog*.BAK -mtime +${TOOLD} | wc -l)
LOGFILES_TO_DELETE=$(ls -lrt boxlog*.BAK | head -$FOUNDFILES )
echo "Hittar $FOUNDFILES filer att ta bort"
echo "Dygn bakåt $TOOLD som är OK"

# echo "$LOGFILES_TO_DELETE"
if [ $FOUNDFILES -gt 0 ]
then
    _start=0

    MESS1="$FOUNDFILES to remove"
    COUNTER=0
    # Proof of concept
    for number in $(seq ${_start} ${FOUNDFILES})
    do
        sleep 0.1
        LOGFILES_TO_DELETE=$(ls -t boxlog*.BAK | head -1 )
        echo "$LOGFILES_TO_DELETE"
        ProgressBar ${number} ${FOUNDFILES} ${LOGFILES_TO_DELETE}
        rm -f "{$LOGFILES_TO_DELETE}" \; >/dev/null 2>&1            
    done
    #        ProgressBar ${COUNTER} ${FOUNDFILES}
    echo " Done removing $FOUNDFILES files"
fi
```

Comment: when you have written this much code, you should easily be able to debug your progress by wrapping troublesome sections of code to show debug info with `set -x ; ... your code .... ; set +x` , or add debug statements like `echo "#DBG: LOGFILES_TO_DELETE=${LOGFILES_TO_DELETE}"` . Glad you solved your problem. Good luk.

Comment: Hi shelter, thks. Did a lot of debugging but never got anywhere until I stumbled over the -delete parameter to find.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found that this code does it

```
for number in $(seq ${_start} ${FOUNDFILES})
    do
        sleep 0.1
        LOGFILES_TO_DELETE=$(ls -rt log*.BAK | head -1 )
        ProgressBar ${number} ${FOUNDFILES}
        find $LOGFILES_TO_DELETE -delete  >/dev/null 2>&1
        echo "$LOGFILES_TO_DELETE"

    done
```

To explain the code:
The loop, goes through the number of FOUNDFILES to delete.
Then the find `ls -rt .. | head -1` extracts the name of one file from the list.
Then ProgressBar steps according to procent-calculation. 
The `find ... -delete` execute the removal of the file.
Finally the last echo outputs the file after the progressbar.

This is close enough, wrong is that the echo adds a newline and that makes a list of rows with  progressbars, one row for each file removed.